# Fedora 20 Gnome session over X11 forwarding not working

Tags: ssh, fedora, gnome, crash, xorg

In previous Fedora/CentOS distributions I was always able to run "gnome-session" over SSH with X11 forwarding.  However, in Fedora 20, I instead get a window with a sad-face graphic that says "Oh no!  Something has gone wrong.  A problem has occurred and the system can't recover.  Please log out and try again."  In the SSH command window I get this:

```
[root@localhost ~]# gnome-session

** (gnome-session-check-accelerated:20362): WARNING **: Couldn't connect to accessibility bus: Failed to connect to socket /tmp/dbus-ygVJHDDRF1: Connection refused
gnome-session-is-accelerated: No hardware 3D support.
gnome-session-check-accelerated: Helper exited with code 256

** (gnome-session-check-accelerated:20372): WARNING **: Couldn't connect to accessibility bus: Failed to connect to socket /tmp/dbus-ygVJHDDRF1: Connection refused
gnome-session-is-accelerated: No hardware 3D support.
gnome-session-check-accelerated: Helper exited with code 256

** (process:20356): WARNING **: software acceleration check failed: Child process exited with code 1
```

I am able to run most applications over X11.  I tried `setenforce 0` and `systemctl stop firewalld` but the problem still occurs.  The end of the "dmesg" output doesn't appear to be useful.   Why would gnome-session fail to run on X11?  Is this related to my other issue with firewall-config? [Fedora 20 FirewallD GUI not working on X11 forwarding](https://superuser.com/questions/700130/fedora-20-firewalld-gui-not-working-on-x11-forwarding)

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your window manager to something that doesn't use 3D acceleration.  Set your Gnome session to fallback mode and it should work fine.

Comment: Can you please elaborate; how do I make this setting?  Is it a function of the server I'm connecting to or of my SSH client?  I'm connecting from Cygwin using XTerm, with the "ssh -X" / "ssh -Y" commands.